# On the function $\log(1+x)$

Tags: inequality, logarithms

I want to know if the inequality $\log(1+x)\leq\alpha\log(1+y)$ for some $\alpha<1$ implies $x\leq\alpha y$.

I went about like this.

$\log(1+x)\leq\alpha\log(1+y)$ implies $(1+x)\leq(1+y)^\alpha\leq1+y^\alpha$ which implies $x\leq y^\alpha$.

Taking $f(y)=\alpha y-y^\alpha$, we see that $f^\prime(y)=\alpha\left(1-\frac{1}{y^{1-\alpha}}\right)$ which is negative for $y<1$. So, I guessed that the assertion might be wrong for $0\leq y<1$ but I can't find points $x_0$ and $y_0$ for which
$$\log(1+x_0)\leq\alpha_0\log(1+y_0)\quad\text{but}\quad x_0\not\leq\alpha_0y_0$$
for some $\alpha_0<1$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality): if $0<\alpha<1$ and $y>-1$, then $(1+y)^\alpha\le1+\alpha y$.

Comment: @TitoEliatron Thanks a lot!